# Make submit button loads the sumbit results in every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My project consists two navbar contents with two different tables displayed when the page is loaded, and a search bar to display search results in a different table.

**The problem** I am facing is, when I click submit button once my search result is shown in a table, but when it is clicked again the navbar content table is displayed.

I doubt it is caused because I hide the navbar content table when the search table is displayed.

I am looking for a solution which make my search result to be diaplayed whenever the submit button is clicked without the page is refreshed.

My `javascript` is:

```js
var getNameOfEmployee = document.getElementById('searchBarInputID');

function displayEmployee() {

  if (getNameOfEmployee.value != "") {
    $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
    AjaxGet();
    myFunction();
  } else {
    alert("Please enter any name of employee that you wish to know the extension code of!");
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("table1ID");
  var y = document.getElementById("table2ID");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}

AjaxGet = function(url, storageLocation, mySuccessCallback) {
  var result = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/path/' + $("#searchBarInputID").val(),
    param: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      storageLocation = data;
      var txt = "";
      var length = Object.keys(storageLocation).length;
      $.each(storageLocation, function(index, value) {
        $("#searchForm #someLabel" + index).val(value.name);
        txt += "<tr><td>" + value.name + "</td><td>" + value.code + "</td></tr>";
      });

      if (txt != "") {
        $("#searchTableID tbody").html(txt);
      }
    }
  }).responseText;
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying yo do here. Do you have a public URL for your project so I could take a look?

Answer (score -2):

You have some conflicts in the code. When you prevent submit and do nothing. Also you have async method and success method that fills the table but you have to show table after success method finishes

```
var getNameOfEmployee = document.getElementById('searchBarInputID');

function displayEmployee() {

  if (getNameOfEmployee.value != "") {
    $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      AjaxGet();
    });
  } else {
    alert("Please enter any name of employee that you wish to know the extension code of!");
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("table1ID");
  var y = document.getElementById("table2ID");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
  }
}

AjaxGet = function(url, storageLocation, mySuccessCallback) {
  var result = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/path/' + $("#searchBarInputID").val(),
    param: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      storageLocation = data;
      var txt = "";
      var length = Object.keys(storageLocation).length;
      $.each(storageLocation, function(index, value) {
        $("#searchForm #someLabel" + index).val(value.name);
        txt += "<tr><td>" + value.name + "</td><td>" + value.code + "</td></tr>";
      });

      if (txt != "") {
        $("#searchTableID tbody").html(txt);
      }

      myFunction();
    }
  }).responseText;
};
```

Comment: You have some conflicts in the code. When you prevent submit and do nothing. Also you have async method and  success method that fills the table but you can show table after success finish

Comment: sorry @Gurkanİlleez I found no difference between your code and mine! Can you please explain me the problem hat you said in your answer?